# SQLite Group BY

Tags: sqlite

i want to Calculate the percentages of some Values between Dates in SQLite Query.

This is how the Rows look like

```
customerId, sex, timeStamp, item
```

My Code

```
 String query = "SELECT *, ROUND((count(sex)*100.0)/(SELECT count(sex) FROM salesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'),2) AS '"+PERCENTAGE+"'   FROM salesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'   GROUP BY sex ORDER BY percentage DESC" ;
```

My Problem is that for example a Male Customer buys 3* Phones it will be stored like this

- Male Customer, Male, timeStamp, Phone
- Male Customer, Male, timeStamp, Phone
- Male Customer, Male, timeStamp, Phone

The timeStamp´s in this example are same because the phones where sold at the same time. I have to store everything separate even if they belong together because of some other reasons.

And now lets say a Female Customer Buys 2* Phones. Then we have

- Male Customer, Male, timeStamp, Phone
- Male Customer, Male, timeStamp, Phone
- Male Customer, Male, timeStamp, Phone
- Female Customer, Female, timeStamp, Phone
- Female Customer, Female, timeStamp, Phone

What i want to get is 50% Male and 50% Female. Im sure it is easy to do it but im stuck with it. I also tried this with GROUP BY sex, timeStamp

```
 String query = "SELECT *, ROUND((count(sex)*100.0)/(SELECT count(sex) FROM salesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'),2) AS '"+PERCENTAGE+"'   FROM salesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'   GROUP BY sex, timeStamp ORDER BY percentage DESC" ;
```

at the end but didn't work

I use the sex and value to populate it in Androids ListView like this

- Male 50%
- Female 50%

Comment: It is working fine in MySQL

Comment: No but what you want to achieve using 50/50?

Comment: I want to see how many of my Customers are Male and how many Female.

Comment: Above query is showing the same

Comment: Is `customerId` unique to each row, or is it the same value for all buys by the same person?

Comment: No customerId is used as Name of the Customer. But sometimes there is a default Value so  i can't use it for this Calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select sex, count(distinct customerId) from salesTable group by sex;
```

This'll give back two rows, e.g.

```
F|3
M|1
```

This gives the total count of females and males. From there you can compute the percentages.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me because it would not count if the Same Customer buys something at a different date/time. I can't even use the timeStamp to distinct because the Values are inserted sometimes one second later because they are inserted one by one. Maybe because the Android Emulator is a bit slower.

Comment: Well if you can't differentiate on identical timestamps nor on the customerId field, I don't know how you are going to uniquely identify customers! What if two different men buy at the same time? You'd need to be able to tell them apart.

Comment: Two different People at the same time is impossible. But maybe i can use between somehow. The timestamps are stored as unix timestamps. It takes about 3-4 Seconds for the user to insert the next Sell if he is really fast. Is there a way to Group or distinct with 2+ and 2- ? I Mean 2 seconds after & before

Comment: I think you need to revisit the decisions behind your schema. It is not fulfilling your needs.